# Which browser-based client-side technology?

Tags: web-applications, client-server, client-side

Back in the day there were only Active X and JavaScript.

Users would turn them off, disabling my apps, or would edit the JS code (usually breaking it). So I switched to strictly server-side, where I have complete control.

Now I am thinking that I might be misisng out on half of the possibilities for browser-based apps.

We are talking business apps here, so maybe I can enforce JS. I guess that Active X gave way to .NET long ago, but what's a good matching client-side tech?

I am a Linux fan and would be happy with a cross-platform solution, but, realistically, 90+% of bussinesses are using Windows and insting on MS IE, no even firefox (at least here in Asia, ymmv)

What's the current state of play, and is there anything that addresses my concerns above?

---

@Oren A makes a good point about about combining client & server side. For server side I have been mainly using PHP but recently have done some .NET stuff (in both C# and VB), and some SOAP.  What's a good combination of client/servertthat works well together? Or do you think them totally independant?

Comment: I've never had a user try to edit the javascript. What sort of users and apps are these that you're having that problem?

Comment: +1 What sorts of users? Malicious ones. Wannabe hackers who think that if they discern a pattern in directoy or field naming, etc, they change it slightly and somethign interesting might happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) (which is a JS library) and [dojo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) (which is a JS toolkit), and if you need more advanced capabilites - there's Flash (there's also Silverlight, but I don't think you'll like it (-:. Should add that both Flash and Silverlight are downloadable plug-ins and that Flash is more popular, but you can read all about that by googling).  Obviously there are many more, but those are the most popular AFAIK.
Flash files are sended to the user "semi-compiled" so he can't mess with them (although I really don't see how that's a problem in the first place).
Anyhow the vast majority of web application use both - client side **and** server side programming languages.
.NET is mostly sever side (Although web forms are somewhat of a client side as well..).
And one last thing - If a user changes your JavaScript and the script doesn't work for him - why is that a problem for you? unless you're talking about [XSS](http://www.virtualforge.de/vmovie/xss_lesson_1/xss_selling_platform_v1.0.html), which you really do need to be aware of..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (+1). I will look into those. I have no objection to SilverLight although (and I could be wrong here) I understand it mainly to add "rich multimedia" to .NET and I don't have much need for that or Flash.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but there is a technology that is useful when you go to the client side.
Javascript template engines, they usually take a JSON as data input, and render the HTML client side.
They help you separate the HTML view and the Javascript logic.

I'm contributing to [PURE](http://beebole.com/pure) which has a quite unobtrusive approach on strictly separating the HTML markup and the JS logic.
There are plenty of other templating solutions if you look on the web. They are mostly based on the Django template pattern (with tags inside the HTML)